# Can I get source file and line number info in stack trace when my assembly is in the ".net 4 gac"?

Tags: .net, gac

I've previously enjoyed source file names and line number information in exception stack traces for GAC-ed assemblies by simply putting the PDB in the same subdirectory in the GAC where the DLL is installed (just like when a DLL is deployed elsewhere on the file system and not "registered" with the GAC, if there is such a thing).

I tried doing the same thing with a .NET 4 assembly residing in \windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\MSIL\MyLibrary, but I'm getting exactly the same stack trace as before, with information from stack frames (method signatures) but no source code information.

The code lives in an IIS worker process. I believe recycling the app pool (which I've done) would be the maximum I'd need to do (in case something has cached somewhere the knowledge that the PDB isn't there) to see the effect (we're logging errors using Exception.ToString() to get the whole chain with stack trace).

Does this not work anymore? Is there some other way? Surely in a LOT of cases the cost of cycles "wasted" to get the full info is extremely low compared to the cost of not having this information. In my case I simply want to make sure I get this in our system test environment, to help make the bugfixing phase proceed a bit faster...

Comment: Show some evidence that you are doing this correctly so we can eliminate the obvious mistakes.  The directory name you quoted cannot be correct, there's no evidence that you changed the build setting so you don't get a PDB with the source+line info stripped.  And use the debugger's Debug + Windows + Modules window.  Right-click your DLL and choose Symbol Load Information.

Comment: Well, I told you the PDB was placed in the same directory as the DLL. though you're correct about the path (it's C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MyLibrary\v4.0_1.0.0.0__332f46e24df61313). The DLL was built in debug configuration (which we haven't changed) in VS-2012. Oddly, I get full stack trace info on the development box, even though I've GAC-ed the assembly but haven't deployed the PDB there. I'm not sure what other "evidence" you need, but interpret your answer to mean "this should work the same as it did before .net 4" - correct?